# Write multiple things in a switch statement in C

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

So i need to have my switch statement go through and write out five two if the user says 52 but i cannot get it pass my 0-9. if they type 0-9 it works perfect but if i try to do any number past that it makes a blank. help!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

        int x;

        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);

        printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

        for(x;x<0;x++);

        switch (x)

        {
        case 0:
                printf("zero");
                break;
        case 1:
                printf("one");
                break;
        case 2:
                printf("two");
                break;
        case 3:
                printf("three");
                break;
        case 4:
                printf("four");
                break;
        case 5:
                printf("five");
                break;
        case 6:
                printf("six");
                break;
        case 7:
                printf("seven");
                break;
        case 8:
                printf("eight");
                break;
        case 9:
                printf("nine");
                break;
        }

        printf("\n\n");



        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Homework, right?  You might want to try writing out in words what you need to do and figure out how to take those words and turn them into code.

Comment: The line `for(x;x<0;x++);` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: (Hints rather than code since this is homework) You could convert `x` to a string using `sprintf`, then loop over the characters in the string, using your switch statement for each one.

Comment: i have not learned sprintf so i won't use it. i'm trying to think around the ways we have learned but its not easy.

Answer (score 3):

```
do {
  switch (x%10) {
    ...
  }
  x = x / 10;
} while (x>0) ;
```

or to get it in the right order use recursion

```
void f(int x) {
  if (x==0) return;
  f(x/10);
  switch(x%10) { ... }
}
```

Comment: For input `52` the user wants the output `five two`. This would print `two five` wouldn't it?

Comment: The special case could be solved with a do-while instead of a while, so it will always run once.

Comment: Yes it will output the digits with the least significant first. But the question is not explicit about the order.

Comment: Thanks @geekster777. I made it a do-while. No need to special case 0.

Comment: yeah i got that far but it does print out second number first. how would i combat that?

Comment: how can i switch the statement to read from left to right in this order 52 to read five two?

Comment: after i tried that if statement it just gives me the second number of the two numbers.

Answer (score 0):

*This question has been [**asked-and-answered**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967008/how-to-get-different-digits-starting-from-the-most-significant-digit-in-a-number) before.*

The for-loop you wrote is empty, because the body of the loop ends with the semi-colon:

```
for(x;x<0;x++) /* Empty Body!!*/ ;
```

The way a typical for loop works is:

```
for( /*Initialize*/;  /*Test*/;  /*Change*/)
{
    /* Body */
}
```

In your case, I think you want:

```
for(int i=0;  i < x; ++i)
{
    switch(x)
    {
         [...]
    }
}
```

This will:

- Initialize i to 0
- Test if i is LESS THAN x (the number you entered)
- Keep increasing i by 1, until it gets up to x.

Comment: the for loop i put in there is just something i tried to get it to work. i thought that when i put in like 15 if will find one but i need to loop it so it also picks out the five. thats where i'm running into my problems. keep in mind i'm a very base level student and i haven't learned a lot of things that would make this easier.

Comment: You can see my answer to a similar question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967008/how-to-get-different-digits-starting-from-the-most-significant-digit-in-a-number

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do. Similar to what @simonc said, it's a good idea to convert the user input to a string, then loop through the characters. For each character, convert it into an `int` and then take that into the switch statement.

EDIT---------------------------

Here's a way with strictly using integers.

First find how many digits your integer has. You can do this by a method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer).

Then do integer division starting from the largest power of 10 that divides the integer you have and divide the divisor by 10 until you reach 1. For example:

If user input is `213`, it has 3 digits. We divide this by `100` first.
`213/100 = 2`

We take the `2` and put it into the switch statement, outputting `2`. Now we're done with the hundreds digit, so now we take the `13` from `213` and divide it by `10`.

`13/10 = 1` So now we output `one`.

Keep doing this process until you get to the ones digit.

Does this make sense?

Comment: not really i guess. sorry this is really tough stuff to learn. :O

Comment: @user2963635 mm which part are you confused? i'll edit the answer to your needs

Comment: is string like a way of commands? if so i have not learned that yet and probably shouldn't be putting down things i haven't learned. and by character do you mean case?

Comment: by string, i mean the string class. It's an array of characters (which is a `char` class). You have not yet seen the `char` or `string` classes?

Comment: i've had char but i have not had string.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with recursion.

```
void printDigit(int x) {

  int digit = x%10;
  if(digit!=x)
    printDigit(x/10);
  switch(digit) {
  ...
  }
}
```

This will print the most significant figure first, unlike the while loops most people are mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to do your homework for you but consider the following pseudo-code:

```
print_text_digits(x)
{
    if (x >= 10) print_text_digits(x / 10);
    switch (x) {
        print "zero" through "nine" as appropriate
    }
}

main()
{
    scan number into x;
    print_text_digits(x);
}
```

This relies on a recursive routine so that you get your digits processed one at a time, with the might significant digit printed first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{

int count = 0;
int x, count2;

printf("Please enter an integer: ");
scanf("%d", &x);

printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

int aux = x;
while(aux>0) {
    aux=aux/10;
    count++;
}
count2 = count;
while(count) {
    aux = x;
    for(int i=count-1;i>0;i--)
        aux=aux/10;
    for(int i=count2-count;i>0;i--)
        aux%=10;
    switch (aux) {
        case 0:
            printf("zero");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("one");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("two");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("three");
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("four");
            break;
        case 5:
            printf("five");
            break;
        case 6:
            printf("six");
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("seven");
            break;
        case 8:
            printf("eight");
            break;
        case 9:
            printf("nine");
            break;
    }
    count--;
    if(count) printf(" ");
}
printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Now, with an input `52` it will propelly return `five two`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char * const num[] = {
    "zero ", "one ", "two "  , "three ", "four ",
    "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine "
};

void printNum(int x)
{
    if (x < 10) {
        printf(num[x]);
        return;
    }
    printNum(x / 10);
    printNum(x % 10);
}

int main (void)
{
    int x;

    printf("Please enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("\nYou have entered:\n\n");

    printNum(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what you are doing what is it called.